# To calculate a moving average for a list of stock data prices in an Oracle DB - is it faster using SQL or Java?

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have an Oracle Database with a table containing asset price data for which I want to calculate a 10-day moving average in a separate column.

Is it faster to use SQL for this or should I load the data into a Java Hashmap/ ArrayList first, do the calculation and transfer the results it back to the Oracle DB afterwards?

The Table looks like this:

```
| ASSET_ID | PRICE | DATE       | MA    |
-----------------------------------------
| 43       | 33.12 | 2018-09-17 | 33.05 |
| 43       | 34.02 | 2018-09-18 | 33.07 |
| 43       | 30.22 | 2018-09-19 | 33.01 |
| 43       | 31.52 | 2018-09-20 | 32.85 |
```

Comment: No need for a stored procedure: `avg(price) over (partition by asset_id order by "DATE" range between ....) as ma`

Comment: It would be faster on db side since you will avoid loading the data in memory on application side.

Comment: The database is the right place for this. It avoids having you transfer all the data to your java application, allocating extra memory for it and transfering it back to your database again. And (depending on your algorithm) the database might be able to do the reading, calculating and writing in one single iteration.

Comment: thanks for the comments! does that also apply for more complex algorithms or is there a limit to what should usefully be done in Oracle?

Comment: it depends on what's being done. For example, your example of "take a load of data from the database, twiddle around with it and then send it back to the database" immediately sounds inefficient, doesn't it? You'd only really want to move that data around if and only if the database couldn't handle the processing. However, if you're getting data from the database and ultimately sending it on somewhere else, it makes sense to do the in-between processing in the most efficient place. That could be inside the database, or in the code that retrieves/receives the data. In short: it depends!

Answer (score 2):

Use `AVG( PRICE ) OVER ( PARTITION BY asset_id ORDER BY "DATE" RANGE BETWEEN 10 PRECEDING AND 0 FOLLOWING )` to get a moving average:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c78b77/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( ASSET_ID, PRICE, "DATE", MA ) AS
SELECT 43, 33.12, DATE '2018-09-17', CAST( NULL AS NUMBER(8,2) ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 43, 34.02, DATE '2018-09-18', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 43, 30.22, DATE '2018-09-19', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 43, 31.52, DATE '2018-09-20', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 43, 32.52, DATE '2018-09-21', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 43, 33.52, DATE '2018-09-22', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 43, 34.52, DATE '2018-09-23', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 43, 35.52, DATE '2018-09-24', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 43, 36.52, DATE '2018-09-25', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 43, 37.52, DATE '2018-09-26', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 43, 38.52, DATE '2018-09-27', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 43, 39.52, DATE '2018-09-28', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 43, 40.52, DATE '2018-09-29', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 43, 41.52, DATE '2018-09-30', NULL FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
MERGE INTO table_name dst
USING (
  SELECT ROWID rid,
         ROUND(
           AVG( price ) OVER (
             PARTITION BY asset_id
             ORDER BY "DATE"
             RANGE BETWEEN 10 PRECEDING AND 0 FOLLOWING
           ),
           2
         ) AS new_MA
  FROM   table_name
) src
ON ( dst.ROWID = src.rid )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET MA = src.new_MA
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c78b77/2/0)**:

```
14 Rows Updated
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c78b77/2/1)**:

```
| ASSET_ID | PRICE |                 DATE |    MA |
|----------|-------|----------------------|-------|
|       43 | 33.12 | 2018-09-17T00:00:00Z | 33.12 |
|       43 | 34.02 | 2018-09-18T00:00:00Z | 33.57 |
|       43 | 30.22 | 2018-09-19T00:00:00Z | 32.45 |
|       43 | 31.52 | 2018-09-20T00:00:00Z | 32.22 |
|       43 | 32.52 | 2018-09-21T00:00:00Z | 32.28 |
|       43 | 33.52 | 2018-09-22T00:00:00Z | 32.49 |
|       43 | 34.52 | 2018-09-23T00:00:00Z | 32.78 |
|       43 | 35.52 | 2018-09-24T00:00:00Z | 33.12 |
|       43 | 36.52 | 2018-09-25T00:00:00Z |  33.5 |
|       43 | 37.52 | 2018-09-26T00:00:00Z |  33.9 |
|       43 | 38.52 | 2018-09-27T00:00:00Z | 34.32 |
|       43 | 39.52 | 2018-09-28T00:00:00Z |  34.9 |
|       43 | 40.52 | 2018-09-29T00:00:00Z | 35.49 |
|       43 | 41.52 | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z | 36.52 |
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That just creates a Query Result though, it does not actually modify anything in the Database. Is there a simple statement how I can transfer the MA column into the original table?

Comment: "INSETR INTO table_name(MA) SELECT [...]"  returns the error "cannot insert NULL into (%s)" even though the select statement itself returns a result.

Comment: @DanielMethner Updated - Use a `MERGE` statement and merge on the `ROWID` pseudo-column.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I will look into the MERGE statement deeper.